# Node Express Validate Form Submission on Post without Reloading but show validation errors

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, ejs

I think I'm missing a fundamental concept and might be reinventing the wheel here. I'm building a web app that will let users post reviews. I'm using EJS, Node, Express, Postgres.  The index page is a web form at the top with a submit button to post a review to the db. The bottom half of the index page is the last 15 reviews from the database.

On initial get request for the page load the database is queried for the last 15 records which are displayed in a table below the form. When an end user fills out the form and it passes validation, it posts to the db and redirects to a success page no problem.

My issue is when the form fails validation. When it fails, I collect the error messages on the server side in an array called alert. I then attempt to re-render the page to display those error messages by the input fields. I realize that now I also have to grab those 15 records from the database so I can re-render the table below the form.

As I have it written here, I am having problems with getting the query results. When I run the code in the debugger, it skips over the line 'arr[1] = getRecords(15)'. So then when it goes to render the page, arr[1] comes back as undefined because the getRecords function never executed. I suspect this is an issue with executing asynchronous/synchronously but I'm not skilled enough to know how to fix it.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this implementation to work, but also am I overcomplicating it? it seems wasteful to query the database just because the form failed validation. It seems like there should be a way to preserve that table that originally rendered and just render the error messages related to the form validation. But I haven't been able to google my way to a solution.

**My initial get request on index that loads data from the db**

app.get('',async (req,res)=>{

```
console.log("hello world?")
const lastTwenty = await pool.query("select *,  TO_CHAR(reviewdate,\'MM-DD-YYYY\') from reviews ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15")

const reformattedDates = lastTwenty.rows.map((r)=>{
    r.reviewdate = dayjs(r.reviewdate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    return r
})

reformattedDates.forEach((rec)=>{
    console.log("revised dates "+ rec.reviewdate)
})

res.render('index', {reviewData: reformattedDates})
```

})

**My post request from a form on the same page that performs validation before letting the post through**

app.post(
'/addRecord',
urlencodedParser,
check('name', 'User name must be 3 characters')
.exists()
.isLength({min:3}),
check('company', 'Company name must not be blank or greater than 50 char')
.exists()
.isLength({min:3})
.isLength({max:50}),
check('country', 'Country must not be blank or greater than 50 char')
.exists()
.isLength({min:3})
.isLength({max:50}),
check('state', 'State/Province name must not be blank or greater than 50 char')
.exists()
.isLength({min:2})
.isLength({max:50}),
check('review', 'Review story must not be blank or greater than 1000 char')
.exists()
.isLength({min:3})
.isLength({max:1000}),

```
 (req,res)=>{
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        //return res.status(422).jsonp(errors.array())
        const alert = errors.array()
        let arr = ['','']
        arr[1] = getRecords(15)
        .then(
            
            res.render('index',{data: {alert: arr[0] = alert, reviewData:arr[1]}})
        )

    }else{
            const {name, company, state, country, review} = req.body
            const reviewdate = dayjs().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
            console.log("todays date is ", typeof reviewdate)
            const newRecord = pool.query("insert into reviews(rName, rCompany, rState, rCountry, rReview, reviewDate) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)",
            [name, company, state, country, review, reviewdate])
            console.log("posting to db")    
            res.render('success', {text:"many success"})
        //res.render('success',{text:'success'})
    }})

    let getRecords = async (alert) => {
        console.log("in get record and qty is ",qtyRecords)
        const queryOutput = await pool.query("select *,  TO_CHAR(reviewdate,\'MM-DD-YYYY\') from reviews ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15")
        const reformattedOutput = queryOutput.rows.map((r)=>{
            r.reviewdate = dayjs(r.reviewdate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
            return r 
        }) 
        return reformattedOutput
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the post to handle form validation failure as per below. Adding the async and try block seemed to do the trick.

```
 (req,res)=>{
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        //return res.status(422).jsonp(errors.array())
        const alert = errors.array()

        async function reRender(alert){
            try{
            const output = await getRecords(15);
            res.render('index', {data: {alert: alert, reviewData: output}})

            }
            catch(e){
                console.log('catch error ',e)
            }         
        }
        reRender(alert);
    }
    else{
            const {name, company, state, country, review} = req.body
            const reviewdate = dayjs().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
            console.log("todays date is ", typeof reviewdate)
            const newRecord = pool.query("insert into reviews(rName, rCompany, rState, rCountry, rReview, reviewDate) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)",
            [name, company, state, country, review, reviewdate])
            console.log("posting to db")    
            res.render('success', {text:"many success"})
        //res.render('success',{text:'success'})
    }
 }
```